# Gradle 2.2.1 error when run cordova build command on CLI

Tags: android, cordova

I have recently updated my Cordova to 5.1.1 along with JDK to 1.7.0.79. I also have created a new Cordova android project. But when I try to Build the project using CLI, it gives me the following error :

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.28 (ia32) and npm.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>F:

F:\>cd shishutosh

F:\shishutosh>cordova build android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "F:\shishutosh\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat""

ANDROID_HOME=E:\Backup\Software\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130729\adt-bundle-windo
ws-x86-20130729\sdk\
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
Running: F:\shishutosh\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b F:\shishutosh\
platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostExcep
tion: services.gradle.org
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java
:178)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLC
onnection.java:997)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConne
ction.java:933)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection
.java:851)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:1301)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:65)
    ... 3 more

F:\shishutosh\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
            throw e;
              ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "F:\shishutosh\platforms\android\
gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b F:\shishutosh\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.grad
le.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Applicatio
n Data\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.
js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)

F:\shishutosh>
```

I have manually installed the Grandle and set the environmental variables. and verified it as below:

```
    F:\Rong>gradle -v

    ------------------------------------------------------------
    Gradle 2.2.1
    ------------------------------------------------------------

    Build time:   2014-11-24 09:45:35 UTC
    Build number: none
    Revision:     6fcb59c06f43a4e6b1bcb401f7686a8601a1fb4a

    Groovy:       2.3.6
    Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
    JVM:          1.7.0_79 (Oracle Corporation 24.79-b02)
    OS:           Windows 2003 5.2 x86
```

My previously created projects running the CLI "BUILD COMMAND" without any error. Can anyone give me some solution on that matter.

Thanks in advance.

N.B. I am behind a corporate proxy.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue . I couldn't figure out, but there is a workaround if you have ANT installed,and configured path . 
Try command "cordova build android -- --ant"
(Still searching for right solution)

Comment: Thanks for the response. cordova build android -- --ant worked for me (I have ANT installed). Please let me know if you find any "right solution" for the problem. Can you please post the workaround url?

Comment: @user3908960 Ok, it was just an issue with proxy. Configure the proxy correctly, set https_proxy in path variable , and things worked fine for me.

Comment: @AbdulKhader could u please tell me how to set the https_proxy in path variable

Answer (score -1):

- This is because of gradle error Download the file
- **http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip**
- and extract it in any of directory and set the path by open cmd and
        enter
- **setx path (extracted direstory)/bin**
- after reopen cmd and check whether the gradle is works or not by
     give
- **gradle -v**
- it shows the gradle version output .
- Now the error is fixed run **ionic build android**